# Center Popup in Current Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, center

I've implemented a JavaScript function that shows a popup when a particular image is clicked; however, the popup and the cover (transparent grey cover behind the popup that when clicked makes the popup go away) won't move to the center of the current window. As the image can be clicked wherever it is visible, the popup needs to open in the center (which will have a dynamic height and static width) of the page in its current position (when the image was clicked). I also need this to work with multi-monitor setups. I found this JavaScript

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {  
    // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox  
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;  
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

    width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
    height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

    // Puts focus on the newWindow  
    if (window.focus) {  
        newWindow.focus();  
    }  
}
```

but I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm not sure how to implement something like this. If there is a fix using HTML and CSS then I'd much prefer that, but a simple JavaScript fix that I can follow is fine. Thanks if you can help.

My code is here: http://jsbin.com/EMAHetA/4/edit

Comment: I'm going to ask a bit of a UX question, but are you sure you actually want a new window, and not some dynamic node overlaying the content in the current window?

Comment: No I definitely want a popup that overlays the content in the current window. You can see what I'm trying to do by looking at the JSBin if you middle-click and go up. I just want it to be centered rather than off the screen somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather not have to answer my own question again, but I've figured out how to do it, and this method isn't in any of the answers. Anyway, the idea is actually rather simple. First determine the dimensions of the popup, which in my case is 1280px x 720px. Then give the popup this css (in context):

```
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-360px 0 0 -640px;
```

What this does is set the position of the popup's top-left corner at the center of the screen, and then set the left and top dimensions of the popup back by half of its own dimensions, effectively moving the center of the popup to the center of the screen. To use this method yourself, all you need to do is adjust the various dimensions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're trying to create here is typically called a **modal**, and it's possible to pull one off in [pure CSS](http://drublic.github.io/css-modal/). You can also implement a modal in jQuery: do some searching for "jquery modal" and see what you get. I recommend [Foundation Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) (if you don't mind including some other useful js) or [Kyle Fox's modal code](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) (super lightweight).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is what I'm trying to do. I'll look into how they made these and hopefully I can make mine simpler (and working).

Answer (score 1):

Using the `PopupCenter` code you have provided, you could do the following.

In *HTML* (I use *JSON* in a data attribute to make it easy). The *class* will be used to find the nodes.

```
<span
    class="popup"
    data-popup='{"s": "http://google.com", "t": "Google", "h": 400, "w": 400}'
>Click me!</span>
```

In *JavaScript*

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { // wait for nodes to exist
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName('popup'), // get all the popups
        i = popups.length; // for iterating
    function clickPopupNode() { // function describing actions to take
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('data-popup'));
        PopupCenter(obj.s, obj.t, obj.h, obj.w);
    }
    while (i-->0) { // iterate over each matching node
        popups[i].addEventListener('click', clickPopupNode); // and attach func
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/96m6a/)

---

Except your `PopupCenter` code function does not seem to work as you intend; try this simplified version instead

```
function PopupCenter(s, t, h, w) {
    var y = (window.screen.height - (h | 0)) / 2,
        x = (window.screen.width - (w | 0)) / 2;
    window.open(
        s, t,
        'scrollbars=yes, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+y+', left='+x
    ).focus();
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/96m6a/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in reply to your comment to the question, I want a popup that overlays the content in the current window - or as I now know they're called thanks to @EricTjossem, a modal.

Comment: Oh, you do those with css positioning tricks. Because you posted the code you did I thought you wanted a new window.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use javascript or any external modal libraries and instead want to use **pure css**, you can just add the following css code to your div element

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/